# Error 'Permission denied (publickey,password)'

Tags: ssh, remote-access, openssh, public-key, rsa

I am trying to connect to a local IP address via SSH from the terminal. The command is

```
ssh -v user@192.168.0.2
```

But it is not connecting. It keeps giving me the error

> "Permission denied (publickey,password)."

I have been searching for ages and just can't find what the issue is. I can connect using the same method via [PuTTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) on windows and can connect via [FileZilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FileZilla)

Full output:

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.2 [192.168.0.2] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/[UserName]/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/UserName/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/UserName/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/UserName/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: [Server Host Key]
debug1: Host '192.168.0.2' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/[UserName]/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/[UserName]/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/[UserName]/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Comment: From the output, it looks like ssh is trying to use an identiy file (lines 5-8 inclusive).  If you have an identity file you are using, be sure the permissions are set so only the owner can read/write.

Comment: What should the permissions be?
`-rw-------  1 Username  staff   314  9 May 00:08 id_ecdsa
-rw-r--r--  1 Username  staff   199  9 May 00:08 id_ecdsa.pub
-rw-------  1 Username  staff  1766  8 May 22:40 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 Username  staff   419  8 May 22:40 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 Username  staff   799  8 May 23:10 known_hosts`

Comment: @harnamc Don't just paste a load from the terminal into a comment.  Can't you see that's barely readable. Just quote the relevant part and snip irrelevant parts..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to add the key again.

First set `PasswordAuthentication yes` in file *sshd_config* at the destination machine, and then do `ssh-copy-id user@host`, log in, and then it will copy the key over.

Now you can set `PasswordAuthentication no` (if you want, for extra security), and you should be able to log in automatically.

You could also use your curiosity and check if id_rsa.pub from the source machine is in the *authorized_keys* file on the destination machine.

Comment: also, I don't think permisions are the issue, but i've read that chmod 600 is fine for all files in ~/.ssh   with 700 for the directory itself so you can list the files in it. Certainly anything less would be a problem

Comment: Spot on mate! worked like a charm

Comment: This doesn't work for me. ssh-copy-id also fails with a similar error message

Comment: @RajeevRanjan You could post a question for that.  Also, I have not used ssh in a while

Comment: @barlop what is  ssh-copy-id user@host log in, and how to do it ?

Comment: @NaomiFridman it's a command eg the guy does it in this 2min video "How to do Passwordless SSH using ssh-copy-id Command" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aVul3y1XjVQ   For ssh on windows, I use cygwin. (it's a way of doing linux commands on windows) , But there is a manual way of doing ssh-copy-id if your ssh implementation doesn't include ssh-copy-id

Comment: @NaomiFridman  this guy has done SSH in windows 10 https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToUseWindows10sBuiltinOpenSSHToAutomaticallySSHIntoARemoteLinuxMachine.aspx  and there is a line there where he takes the contents of the local file id_rsa.pub and he appends it to a file on the remote machine called authorized_keys  That's what ssh-copy-id does. He actually used a one line command to do what ssh-copy-id does. You can also do it with a text editor, just taking the contents of one file and adding it as a line in another file

Comment: @barlop thank you. it solved it :)

Answer (score 5):

You probably have set `PasswordAuthentication no` in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` on the machine where you start `ssh`. This file is used for outgoing ssh connections.

The same setting also exists in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (`sshd`, not `ssh`!) of your remote machine for incoming ssh connections. But if this settings were wrong it would also not have worked with `putty` or with `ssh` from another computer.

The setting in both files have to be set to `PasswordAuthentication yes` to make it work.

When you are not an admin or just don't want to change your local `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` permanently, you can also pass the parameter to the ssh command line:

```
ssh -o "PasswordAuthentication yes" yourserverip
```

Comment: I have been trying for hours to ssh into a machine, without any success, including with `ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no`. I just tried your `ssh -o "PasswordAuthentication yes"` and I'm finally in!

Comment: thanks. that was the correct solution. linked your solution in that question. maybe you want to elaborate. 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15138/how-to-force-ssh-client-to-use-only-password-auth#comment1395759_15141

Comment: Have "PasswordAuthentication yes" on server's sshd_config and client's ssh_config, restarted ssh services, still getting same error.

Answer (score 4):

It might be different because it looks like you are connecting to `localhost` or something (`192.168.0.2` or is that just for the question?).

What often solves things like this is to edit the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file and delete the entry for the domain you are connecting to, it will re-prompt you for ssh credentials and avoid problems caused by incorrect "expectations".

Comment: The localhost 192.168.0.2 is a local vpn server that has ssh enabled. I can connect to it from any other means. I have deleted the entire in the ~/.ssh/known_hosts and also completely removed the file and recreated it. But the problem still exists. Its issue is just when trying to connect from my mac. I have tried connection via putty from my window laptop and it works fine. Even sftp via filezilla works perfectly fine.

Comment: Also try deleting `id_rsa.pub` ?

Comment: @beroe I think id_rsa.pub doesn't do much. I vaguely recall from a test that it seems ssh works the same with or without id_rsa.pub . I think ssh    doesn't use the public key in the pub file even though the contents are the same.

Comment: Tried removing and recreating all the keys still had same problem. What worked was set PasswordAuthentication yes in sshd_config and copy keys accross with `ssh-copy-id user@host`

Comment: Glad you got it figured out and thanks for the update.

Answer (score 3):

First run `cat $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` on your computer. That will get you a key. Save this key somewhere.

Then open this file by running `vim $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the computer that you're are ssh'ing to. Then copy the key in a new line of this file and close it by typing `:wq`.

You are all set.

Comment: On top of that OpenSSH package includes [ssh-copy-id](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-copy-id) command which basically does the some in one command

Comment: The client's public key is in `user/.ssh/authorized_keys` and `ProgramData/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys` on the Windows 10 SSHD server. Still I get `Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).` on the Mac client when trying to access the server PC...